# I'm trying to populate a select box via Ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to load a list on a select box but have not get it to work. If I use simple text input fields and send the response to a div it works fine, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to type inside the select box and have the list appear. This is my Code: (no Jquery)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function Peticion_Ajax(){
        var coso = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "script2.php";
        var primer_nombre = document.getElementsByName('nombre_inicial').value;
        var vars = "nombre_peticion="+primer_nombre;
        coso.open("POST", url, true);
        coso.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        coso.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(coso.readyState == 4 &&coso.retorno == 200) {
            var return_data =coso.responseText;
          document.getElementById("retorno").innerHTML = return_data;
          }
        }

        coso.send(vars);
        document.getElementById("retorno");
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Ajax Post to PHP and Get Return Data</h2>
    <select id="retorno" name="nombre_inicial" onkeyup="Peticion_Ajax();">
     <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecciona aqui</option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged as php and mysql?

Comment: Thanks for tour kind response. I Tagged PHP andas MySQL because this question can allaso be unswered by any PHP MySQL expert.

Comment: What response you are receiving in coso or coso.responseText? Is it josn, array or making html with <option>value</option> etc.. Directly passing select tag innerhtml

Comment: Hello Dipti, It's <option>value</option> but I get no reply at all.